# json and files attributes of the requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

Is it OK to use `json` and `files` attributes at the same time in `requests.post()` method ?
I'm asking because I'm getting 500 error without specific error output from the server.

```
        data = {
            'first_name': self.ids['first_name'].text,
            'middle_name': self.ids['middle_name'].text,
            'last_name': self.ids['last_name'].text,
            'new_comment': self.ids['comment'].text
        }
       files = {'image_file1': open(self.file_path1, 'rb')}
       headers = {'enctype': 'multipart/form-data', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36'}
       response = requests.post('http://localhost/users/add', json=data, files=files, headers=headers)
```

And I get `None` from the below variables in back-end:

```
post_data = request.get_json()
image_file1 = request.files.get('image_file1')
```

**Updated code:**

front-end:

```
data = {
        'first_name': self.ids['first_name'].text,
        'middle_name': self.ids['middle_name'].text,
        'last_name': self.ids['last_name'].text,
        'new_comment': self.ids['comment'].text
    }
files = {'image_file1': open(self.file_path1, 'rb'), 'data': json.dumps(data)}
headers = {...}
response = requests.post('http://localhost/users/add', files=files, headers=headers)
```

Flask back-end:

```
post_data = json.loads(request.files['data'])
print(post_data)
image_file1 = request.files.get('image_file1')
```

Flask throws `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not FileStorage`

Comment: No, you cannot use both since files only works with urlencoded POST payload. Consider putting the file data inside the JSON object

Comment: When I move the image upload into `data` object I get: `TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable`

Comment: You can only but the data of the file in the JSON, the file handle is simply a reference to a operating system port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have both files and data, so you'll need to put one inside the other.

Putting binary files to JSON is inefficient and error-prone.

So you can put data inside files like this:

```
requests.post(
    '...', 
    files={
         'f': open('...'), 
         'data': json.dumps({...})  # move data here
    },
    headers={...}
)
```

At server side though you need to alter your code, in flask that would be

```
- request.json
+ json.load(request.files['data'])
```

Comment: From Flask I'm getting `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not FileStorage` it's complaining about me passing file in a wrong form.

Comment: I checked my code and `json.load(request.files['data'])` works fine

Comment: json.load(), not json.loads() as you pass a file object, not a string

Comment: You rock ! I knew about `loads()` but didn't about `load()`. So `loads()` is for handling strings and `load()` for handling files.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how can achieve what you want:**

```
files = {'image_file1': open(self.file_path1, 'rb')}
data = {
        'first_name': self.ids['first_name'].text,
        'middle_name': self.ids['middle_name'].text,
        'last_name': self.ids['last_name'].text,
        'new_comment': self.ids['comment'].text
    }

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

requests will send a `multi-part` form POST body with the `image_file1` field set to the contents of the `file_path1` file.

Comment: Did you mean `data=data` in the requests call ? This would throw `Undefined` for `values`.

Comment: @road_runner Yes, my bad. I fixed it